# Complete and uncompleted todos

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
//selectors

const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');
//event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);

//funtions
function addTodo(event) {

    //prevent form from submiting
    event.preventDefault();


/// todo div

const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

//create li
const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

//check mark button
const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
completedButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
//check trash button
const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
trashButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

//append to list
todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

//clear todoinput value
todoInput.value="";


}

function deleteCheck(e){
    const item = e.target;
    //delete todo
    if(item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
      const todo = item.parentElement;

      //animation
      todo.classList.add("fall");
      todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
        todo.remove();
      });


     
    }

    //check mark
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
      const todo =  item.parentElement;
      todo.classList.toggle("completed");
  }
    
}

function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = [...todoList.children];
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
                case "completed":
                    if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                        todo.style.display = "flex";

                    } else {
                        todo.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    case "uncompleted":
                        if(!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                            todo.style.display = "flex";
                        } else {
                            todo.style.display = "none";
                        }
                   
        }
    });

}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda085);
}
header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

header,form{
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

form input, form button{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    background: white;

}

form button{
    color: #d88771;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
form button:hover{
    background: #d88771;
    color: white;
}

.todo-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.todo-list{
    min-width: 30%;
    list-style: none;

}
.todo {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    
}
.todo li{
    flex: 1;
}
.trash-btn, .complete-btn{
    background: #ff6f47;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
}


.complete-btn{
    background: rgb(73,204,73);
}
.todo-item{
    padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
}
.fa-trash, .fa-check{
    pointer-events: none;;
}

.completed{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fall{
    transform: translateY(8rem) rotateZ(20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}

.select{
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
select{
    color: #ff6f47;
    width: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.select::after{
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff6f47;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.select:hover::after{
    background: white;
    color: #ff6f47;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <h1>Yours todos</h1>
   </header>
   <form>
       <input type="text" class="todo-input">
       <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
           <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
       </button>
       <div class="select">
           <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
               <option value="all">All</option>
               <option value="completed">Completed</option>
               <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
           </select>
       </div>
   </form>

   <div class="todo-container">
       <ul class="todo-list">
          
       </ul>
   </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When im use menu with completed and all its popin :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at app.js:79
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo (app.js:76)
```

```js
//selectors

const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');
//event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);

//funtions
function addTodo(event) {

    //prevent form from submiting
    event.preventDefault();


/// todo div

const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

//create li
const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

//check mark button
const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
completedButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
//check trash button
const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
trashButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

//append to list
todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

//clear todoinput value
todoInput.value="";


}

function deleteCheck(e){
    const item = e.target;
    //delete todo
    if(item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
      const todo = item.parentElement;

      //animation
      todo.classList.add("fall");
      todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
        todo.remove();
      });


     
    }

    //check mark
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
      const todo =  item.parentElement;
      todo.classList.toggle("completed");
  }
    
}

function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
                case "completed":
                    if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                        todo.style.display = "flex";

                    } else {
                        todo.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    
        }
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda085);
}
header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

header,form{
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

form input, form button{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    background: white;

}

form button{
    color: #d88771;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
form button:hover{
    background: #d88771;
    color: white;
}

.todo-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.todo-list{
    min-width: 30%;
    list-style: none;

}
.todo {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    
}
.todo li{
    flex: 1;
}
.trash-btn, .complete-btn{
    background: #ff6f47;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
}


.complete-btn{
    background: rgb(73,204,73);
}
.todo-item{
    padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
}
.fa-trash, .fa-check{
    pointer-events: none;;
}

.completed{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fall{
    transform: translateY(8rem) rotateZ(20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}

.select{
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
select{
    color: #ff6f47;
    width: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.select::after{
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff6f47;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.select:hover::after{
    background: white;
    color: #ff6f47;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <h1>Yours todos</h1>
   </header>
   <form>
       <input type="text" class="todo-input">
       <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
           <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
       </button>
       <div class="select">
           <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
               <option value="all">All</option>
               <option value="completed">Completed</option>
               <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
           </select>
       </div>
   </form>

   <div class="todo-container">
       <ul class="todo-list">
          
       </ul>
   </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Im tring to build to do list but i have problem with show completed and uncompleted todos code looks good but its poppin a type error. I dont know its popin problem with the display  if i try to display other stuff its diplaed normaly .Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the i [

```js
//selectors

const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');
//event listeners
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);

//funtions
function addTodo(event) {

    //prevent form from submiting
    event.preventDefault();


/// todo div

const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
todoDiv.classList.add("todo");

//create li
const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

//check mark button
const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
completedButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
//check trash button
const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
trashButton.innerHTML= '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

//append to list
todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

//clear todoinput value
todoInput.value="";


}

function deleteCheck(e){
    const item = e.target;
    //delete todo
    if(item.classList[0] === 'trash-btn'){
      const todo = item.parentElement;

      //animation
      todo.classList.add("fall");
      todo.addEventListener("transitionend", function(){
        todo.remove();
      });


     
    }

    //check mark
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
      const todo =  item.parentElement;
      todo.classList.toggle("completed");
  }
    
}

function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all" :
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
                case "completed":
                    if(todo.classList.contains("done")) {
                        todo.style.display = "flex";

                    } else {
                        todo.style.display = "none";
                    }
        }
    });
}
```

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    color: white;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #f6d365, #fda085);
}
header{
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

header,form{
    min-height: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

form input, form button{
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: none;
    background: white;

}

form button{
    color: #d88771;
    background: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;

}
form button:hover{
    background: #d88771;
    color: white;
}

.todo-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}
.todo-list{
    min-width: 30%;
    list-style: none;

}
.todo {
    margin: 0.5rem;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    
}
.todo li{
    flex: 1;
}
.trash-btn, .complete-btn{
    background: #ff6f47;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1rem;
}


.complete-btn{
    background: rgb(73,204,73);
}
.todo-item{
    padding: 0rem 0.5rem;
}
.fa-trash, .fa-check{
    pointer-events: none;;
}

.completed{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.fall{
    transform: translateY(8rem) rotateZ(20deg);
    opacity: 0;
}

select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}

.select{
    margin: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

}
select{
    color: #ff6f47;
    width: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1rem;
}
.select::after{
    content: "\25BC";
    position: absolute;
    background: #ff6f47;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.select:hover::after{
    background: white;
    color: #ff6f47;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To do list</title>
</head>
<body>
   <header>
       <h1>Yours todos</h1>
   </header>
   <form>
       <input type="text" class="todo-input">
       <button class="todo-button" type="submit">
           <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
       </button>
       <div class="select">
           <select name="todos" class="filter-todo">
               <option value="all">All</option>
               <option value="done">done</option>
               <option value="uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
           </select>
       </div>
   </form>

   <div class="todo-container">
       <ul class="todo-list">
          
       </ul>
   </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: I dont know why i cant add the photo so i just cpo&paste here:app.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined
    at app.js:79
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLSelectElement.filterTodo (app.js:76)
(anonymous) @ app.js:79
filterTodo @ app.js:76

Answer (score 0):

**filterTodo** method

```
const todos = todoList.childNodes;
```

The **childNodes** property returns a collection of a node's child nodes, as a NodeList object.
Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes. Comments are also considered as nodes.

You only need element nodes, to get element nodes, use **children** property

```
const todos = todoList.children;
```

This will return HTMLCollection which is not a normal array which you can loop through, you need to convert it to the simple array, to do  this, use spread operator (...)

```
const todos = [...todoList.children];
```

## Solution

```
function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = [...todoList.children];
    todos.forEach(function(todo, index) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all" :
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
            case "completed":
                if(todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                }
                else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                if(!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                }
                else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have another problem now its not showing another children "completed". I update the code , take a look. I should create other property for this children?

Comment: In option list you're using `done` class while in your `filterTodo` method you are matching with `completed` value. This makes the problem. Moreover you've  not added a switch case for `uncompleted` todos.  Simply use this condition => `if(!todo.classList.contains("completed"))`

Comment: I already changed both things  (look at the last code update) but problem still exist you can try how it work ...